# Choose a positive number $k > 1$ so that $b^k \equiv a \pmod{91}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

> Variables a and b are integers: $b ≡ a \pmod {91}$ and $\gcd(a, 91) = 1$.
>
> - (a) Choose a positive number $k > 1$ so that $b^k ≡ a \pmod {91}$.
> - (b) What is $a \pmod {91}$ if $b = 53$?

Here is how I tried to do it:

- a)

  $b^k ≡ a \mod 91$

  $b^{k-1}*b ≡ a*1 \pmod {91}$

  $b^{k-1} ≡ 1\pmod {91}$

  Now $\Phi (91) = 72$ gives $b^{72} = 1 \pmod {91}$
  so k = 73.
- b)

  $53^{73} = 53^{72} * 53 ≡ 53\ \pmod {91}$

I am wondering if I got it right and if I made any algebraic blunders.

Thank you

Comment: The answer to $a$ is correct.  I have no idea what $b$ is asking..it appears to just be asking for $b\pmod {91}$, in which case your answer is correct though it has nothing to do with $73$ (but I suspect the problem was poorly transcribed).

Comment: Note:  $73$ is not the smallest value you might have taken.  $13$ works (exercise).  But the problem statement doesn't appear to call for the minimal $k$.

Comment: I remember my professor published a paper for covering the general case and made an algorithm to solve this using computer

Comment: Part (b) makes no sense as posed. Please double check that you have not misquoted it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Actually we need to use [Carmichael](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelFunction.html) Function

$\lambda(91)=[6,12]=12$  which should be the highest exponent for any integer $a,(a,91)=1$

Now $53\equiv-3\pmod7\implies53^3\equiv(-3)^3\equiv1\pmod7$

Again, $53\equiv1\pmod{13}$

$\implies53^{[1,3]}\equiv1\pmod{[13,7]}$